# How to make an action that contains keyframes from 2 or more different objects?

Tags: animation, keyframes

I think the title sums it up, I want to be able to have a special parent object that has one animation that stores the every objects part of that animation. for example, I have a sphere and 2 cubes one on each side of the sphere. I want the cubes to move in 2 different directions, and have the sphere to hold on to an animation that has the keyframes for both the cubes in the same action. However, there is a problem. I select all the objects and I > Location, and the last selected object overwrites the keyframes of the others. How can I fix this?

EDIT

I'm going to keep what's here but sort of reclarify what I'm saying in this paragraph.

So I want to store multiple objects locations or any other value in the same action together, so that I can have multiple objects work together for an animation but not have separate actions for every single part, especially if the actions are supposed to play together at the same time. I hope I have clarified somewhat better this time. Thanks.

Comment: I find your statement unclear and difficult to understand.   Others may find it easy to understand.  I am suggesting you write your question again so that you will get more prompt assistance.  Perhaps if you take the time to include a picture that would be good. You wrote [have the sphere to hold on to an animation that has the keyframes].  I do not understand what you wrote.   Are you copying some use of an action that you seen demonstrated?  Inventing some new use of an action? I may try to guess what you goal is.

Comment: Have you used the Blender parent/child concept or an amature?  Would a Copy Location constraint help you?

Comment: I wish a copy location constraint would help, but I need all the objects to be children of some controller object. I heard that way I can store all the animation data on one action on the controller

Comment: Let me ask - is it true that if an object is a child of another, its animation can be stored in the parent along with the parents animation?

Comment: No. Not true.  You have not placed a picture as suggested.  I may be of little help to you.  I suggest you use the tools in way that you have seen demonstrated.  Use demonstrated techniques as far as you can in useful combination.  I suggest you think more openly about the problem and use Blender jargon rather than your own jargon.  State and show your general goal so people have a chance of helping you.  Rather than us have some long discussion in comments your question needs to be improved.  Seek to explain the problem in a way that a non Blender user would understand the general problem.

Comment: My apologies. Let me clarify my question and notify you when such has been done.

Comment: The question has been updated. I hope you aren still here so I can get the necessary help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are exporting to a game why can't you just have each of them in different nla strips and have them going on in the same key frames? You would then just export them and have them all play at the same time.

Comment: Im still working, and its killing me. Dont you think an animation set for even every bullet is a little excessive?

Comment: Sry that is the only way I know.... Can you tell me what you are doing multiple bullet animations for? You could just assign them to the same bone structure in Ue4 and only have to do it for 1 bullet.

Answer (score 0):

You could select two or more different actions in the NLA editor to create a meta strip of actions by pressing Shift + G. All the actions of a meta strip will move together inside the editor, which is what I think you wanted.

You can read more about the NLA editor at http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Rking/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation/Editors/NLA

Comment: Well the problem is I need to export it to my game will that work

Comment: To be perfectly honest, I have no idea but I would guess against my answer working in that case. If you are trying to export your actions to a game I would suggest looking at this post here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/60251/combining-animations-for-colllada-export